# findall function grabbing the wrong info

Tags: python-2.7, findall

I am trying to writing a piece of python to read my files. The code is below:

```
import re, os
captureLevel = []   # capture read scale.
captureQID = []   # capture questionID.  
captureDesc = []   # capture description.
file=open(r'E:\Grad\LIS\LIS590 Text mining\Final_Project\finalproject_data.csv','rt')
newfile=open('finalwordlist.csv','w')
mytext=file.read()

for row in mytext.split('\n'):
    grabLevel=re.findall(r'(\d{1})+\n',row) 
    captureLevel.append(grabLevel)      
    grabQID=re.findall(r'(\w{1}\d{5})',row)  
    captureQID.append(grabQID)              #ERROR LINE.
    grabDesc=re.findall(r'\,+\s+(\w.+)',row)
    captureDesc.append(grabDesc)

    lineCount = 0
    wordCount = 0
    lines = ''.join(grabDesc).split('.')
    for line in lines:
          lineCount +=1 
          for word in line.split(' '):
                 wordCount +=1
                 newfile.write(''.join(grabLevel) + '|' + ''.join(grabQID) + '|' + str(lineCount) + '|' + str(wordCount) + '|' + word + '\n')
```

newfile.close()

Here are three lines of my data:

`a00004," another oakstr eetrequest, helped student request item",2
a00005, asked retiree if he used journal on circ list,2
a00006, asked scientist about owner of some archival notes,2`

Here is the result: 
`22|a00002|1|1|a00002,
22|a00002|1|2|
22|a00002|1|3|scientist
22|a00002|1|4|looking
22|a00002|1|5|for`

The first column of the result should be just one number, but why is it printing out a two digit number?

Any idea what is the problem here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is the tab and space difference again. Need to be careful especially for Python. Spaces are not treated as equivalent to tab. Here is a helpful link talking about the difference: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. To be brief, space is recommended for indentation in the post. However, I find Tab works fine for indentation too. It is important to keep indentation consistent. So if you use tab, make sure you use it all the way.